# LNK2001 in my Imgui menu code, but I have all the correct includes

Tags: c++, directx, imgui

I am having a problem with getting my Imgui menu that I am creating to work, I have no errors but one, this unresolved external LNK2001. I have everything properly included for this line, and the definition is in d3d9.h which is in my [includes](https://gyazo.com/f3b93560705e009db9c2e92959529c52). Any help would be appreciated. If anything else needs to be provided LMK.

[Error](https://gyazo.com/2e4c00dfedffb6793d0a09c4a59b26ba)
[Error Line (first line)](https://gyazo.com/089c2ad8fb16b826bc3f55c6344ca4f5)

Comment: It seems your linker setting (especially linker input setting) is not appropriate.

Comment: You need (most probably) to link with `d3d9.lib`, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-direct3dcreate9

Comment: Building a C++ program is a multi-step process: 1) Edit source; 2) Compile source to object files; 3) Link object files into the executable program. Include (header) files are processed in the compilation to object files. Actually getting the library and fetching the code itself from the library happens when linking. You have a linker error, an error in the last step. I.e. the problem isn't your includes or header file usage.

Comment: Furthermore, please don't post images of text, copy-paste the actual text into the question itself. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question, to include the full and complete build output (also as text) and [how to format] your questions nicely.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out, I really appreciate it. I recently just started with c++ and learned it through solo learn, so there are some things I just haven't perfected yet.